# Live RTMPS stream to Wowza

Tags: wowza

I set up a Wowza server and succeeded to stream RTMP to it from an Android device using a third party library.

The library can also stream RTMPS. 
I checked the Wowza documentation and I didn't see that it can ingest RTMPS or any other encrypted stream (although can stream RTMPS to players).

It is possible to ingest RTMPS live stream with Wowza?

Answer (score 0):

If your Android library you are using is attempting to push the stream into Wowza, it would not be supported.  If somehow you are trying to ingest the stream from the device, this should likely work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Stream lock you can deliver the RTMPS to the Player..

Option 1 : Stream lock - Self Signed - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-request-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority

Option 2 : Stream Lock - You will get 2 Stream lock .JKS file from wowza if you are using any subscription based streaming engine.

After configuring the Stream Lock you can deliver the RTMPS from wowza.